# Angulajs Ui-Grid delete row from Database

Tags: angularjs

Hi i am developing a small application using Angularjs and Ui-grid. On one of the page i am showing all the rows from one table into the Ui-grid. In the last column of the grid i am keeping a delete button to delete the row.

Here is the code for data binding

```
scope.loadGrid = function() 

  var http = $resource(baseURL + '/api/AllInvoices', {/* No paramter */}, 
                            {'get' : {method : 'GET', isArray : true, cache : false, 
                                            timeout : 500, showSpinner : true}});

  $scope.gridOptions = {enableColumnMenus: false};
  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
       { name: '', field: 'Check', cellTemplate: '<md-checkbox aria-label="Checkbox 1"></md-checkbox>'},
       { field: 'InvoiceNumber', cellClass: 'address' },
       { name: 'Date', field: 'InvoiceDate'},
       { field: 'Status'},
       { field: 'Amount' },
       { name: 'Location From', field: 'LocationFrom'},
       { name: 'Location To', field: 'LocationTo'},
       { field: 'Action', cellTemplate: '<img src="svg/delete.png" alt="Description" ng-click="grid.appScope.Delete(row)"/>'},
     ];


   http.get().$promise.then(function (data) {
         $scope.gridOptions.data =  data;
    }, function (reason) {
           alert (reason);
      });
 }
```

Delete method

```
$scope.Delete = function(row) {
        var index = $scope.gridOptions.data.indexOf(row.entity);
        $scope.gridOptions.data.splice(index, 1);
    };
```

Can someone suggest how i can get the unique value from each row and pass the value to delete web api call.

Answer (score 0):

Had to do this the hard way. Not a thing in documentation. I am using vm as controller so my row button click is

```
 ng-click="grid.appScope.vm.confirmDelete(row)"
```

Then in the controller register gridApi

```
onRegisterApi: function (api) {
        gridApi = api;
    }
```

And then I had to find a way to ma

`vm.confirmDelete = function (row) {

        var orgID = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < gridApi.grid.rows.length; i++){
                for (var j = 0; j < row.grid.rows.length; j++){
                    if (gridApi.grid.rows[i].GridRow == row.grid.rows[j].GridRow) {
                        orgID = row.entity.neighborhoodOrganizationID;
                    }
                }
            }
            var data = $.param({ id: orgID});`